# Running an executable on a Windows volume under Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, c++

I have a dual-boot Windows/Ubuntu system. I have a executable file generated from a c++ file in a folder on a Windows volume (which is accessible on Ubuntu) and would like to run it on Ubuntu. The straightforward answer would have been to move the executable file to an Ubuntu volume and run it but this is part of a huge project and I do not have the required space in Ubuntu to move the entire project.

So is it possible to run the executable from my terminal in Ubuntu?

When I try running it from the terminal using the command ./learn, I get the error ./learn: Permission Denied.

I even tried with sudo but it doesn't work.

Comment: you are trying to run a Windows .exe on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

Was your file compiled for Windows? An exe? In that case, copying the file won't help you, since it's using Windows system calls and not Linux's. The fact your file is not on Ubuntu partition makes no difference, even if you copy the file for your Ubuntu partition it won't work.

You may try the following:

- **Use a virtualization layer such as [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)).** Probably the easiest one for you. This will translate the Windows system calls of your software to match Linux ones. Wine should be available through Canonical repository, but I'm not sure.
- **Recompile your program for Linux.** If you don't have enough space to move your project from one partition to another, you probably don't have space to do a compilation. Also, if your software relies on a lot on Windows-only libraries, you'll have to replace them, which can take time. Porting a software can be complex.
- **Install a Windows virtual machine.** This is the roughly the same as booting into your Windows partition, so I guess you're not interested in this option. Popular virtualization methods include **VirtualBox** and **VMWare**. I personally use VirtualBox.

More on this:

- [System call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)

Answer (score 0):

The permission denied error is due to ownership and permissions for the files that can be solved by chown and chmod command give the right ownership and right permission. but I donot think that would work because the binary for windows by compiler at windows and for compiler on Linux are different so I suggest to compile on Linux again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you compile on Ubuntu and you want to use windows partition as a target of the executable file (which is not a win32 exe!). In this case the most easier solution is to mount your windows partition with `umask=000,dmask=000,fmask=000`. This will set 777 permission for everything. But if you'd like to be aware of security, then you should not allow this. Depending on your user/group settings you could set e.g: `022`

Permissions for ntfs and vfat file systems must be set with the `dmask`, `fmask` and `umask` options. `dmask` controls permissions for directories, `fmask` controls permissions for files, and `umask` controls both. Since these options set masks, they should be the compliment of the permissions you want. For example, rwx for the owner and rw for others is 022 rather than 755.

You can give these options directly to `mount` command:

```
sudo mount /dev/your_win_partition /media/drive_c -o remount,umask=000,dmask=000,fmask=000
```

If you want to make it persistent, then you should add these options to `/etc/fstab`. More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab).